# How to allow the user to select which duplicate element they want to keep based on a certain amount of columns (MySQL PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv, duplicates

**Info**

I have written a php script that takes a csv file and uploads it to a MySQL database. Within this script, i check for duplicates based on the four columns first_name, last_name, birthdate, and phone.

```
$duplicateQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM students
        WHERE first_name ='$firstName'
          AND last_name ='$lastName'
          AND birthDate = '$dateOfBirth'
          AND phone='$homeNumber'");
```

If the query returns 0 it is unique and the element gets inserted into the database. However, the script i want to upload contains many human input errors(in one of the four columns). Hence i have four other statements each selecting if three out of the four elements are identical.

```
$duplicateQueryCase1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM students
          WHERE first_name ='$firstName' AND last_name ='$lastName'
            AND birthDate = '$dateOfBirth'");
$duplicateQueryCase2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM students
          WHERE first_name ='$firstName' AND last_name ='$lastName'
            AND phone='$homeNumber'");
$duplicateQueryCase3 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM students
          WHERE first_name ='$firstName' AND birthDate = '$dateOfBirth'
            AND phone='$homeNumber'");
$duplicateQueryCase4 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM students
          WHERE last_name ='$lastName' AND birthDate = '$dateOfBirth'
            AND phone='$homeNumber'");
```

**Question**

If so, i would like to open a popup message to display the information of each element, that then prompts the user to select which of the elements they would like to keep. I plan on doing nothing and keeping the first element if they select the first option, else updating the info in MySQL to the second element. I am stumped in my approach to this problem, is checking each of the queries and then using a popup with forms a good method or is there a more efficient way to do this. Insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: What part has you stumped? The JS, the AJAX, etc. Your queries could be merged into a single query, returning a code to indicate which condition was met, but other than that, your question is too broad.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Take a look at the links in my comment above to see how you might ask a question that will get useable answers.

Comment: I am mainly stumped in the approach i need to take in order to do this. I am new to the php language, and have tried to find a thread asking the same question but was unable to do so. I am not asking for the code but simply a route or some insight as to the best way to accomplish this. Sorry, new to asking on here.

Comment: I have edited the question section to make it a bit more clear for now and i will look into those links, thanks

Comment: Since you are importing a CSV file that presumably has many rows, a popup doesn't seem appropriate. Instead, display a grid of suspect rows and allow the user (via checkbox or radio button) to select which rows to retain. Then submit the form/grid and complete processing of the CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One area of improvement might be to use a single query to determine if a row should be inserted or if the user should be questioned.

The following query will calculate the number of the 4 columns that match as a score. The score returns the number of columns that match, and only those rows where at least 3 of the columns match.

```
SELECT 
    `id`,
    `first_name`,
    `last_name`,
    `birthdate`,
    `phone`,
    IF(`first_name` = '$firstName',1,0) +
    IF(`last_name` = '$lastName',1,0) +
    IF(`birthdate` = '$birthdate',1,0) +
    IF(`phone` = '$phone',1,0) as `score`
FROM students 
WHERE 
    IF(`first_name` = '$firstName',1,0) +
    IF(`last_name` = '$lastName',1,0) +
    IF(`birthdate` = '$birthdate',1,0) +
    IF(`phone` = '$phone',1,0) >= 3
```

Comment: And be sure to escape the strings before some hacker attacks with "SQL Injection".

Comment: I would suggest using a parameterized query with either mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Great this is definitely more efficient than having four separate queries!